# Using LLDB for IOS debug class member variable NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, lldb

Does anyone know how to get the value for class member variable in IOS ?

I try to use LLDB to debug NSArray in class member variable.

After I run this

```
__cellDataShadowArray2D = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil], nil];
```

When I check the value using LLDB (print object), I always get this.

```
(lldb) po __cellDataShadowArray2D
(NSArray *) $66 = 0x001e8894 <object returned empty description>

(lldb) p __cellDataShadowArray2D
(NSArray *) $67 = 0x001e8894

(lldb) po [__cellDataShadowArray2D count]
2012-04-24 10:10:38.535 SOME [61985:15803] -[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8894
(id) $68 = 0x00000000 <nil>

(lldb) po [__cellDataShadowArray2D retainCount]
(id) $69 = 0xffffffff [no Objective-C description available]

(lldb) p (int) [__cellDataShadowArray2D retainCount]
(int) $70 = -1

(lldb) p (int) [__cellDataShadowArray2D count]
2012-04-24 10:11:31.333 SOME [61985:15803] -[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8894
(int) $71 = 0
```

Comment: Are you using lldb immediately after doing the alloc? Is it possible that the object has been deallocated?

Comment: Also, what is the type of __cellDataShadowArray2D ?

Comment: What do you mean by "class member variable?" There are no class variables in ObjC. Do you mean an instance variable? Or a static variable?

Comment: Note that `po` is for printing _objects_ as you discover - no point using it for `[foo retainCount]`, which returns an `NSUInteger`

Comment: My strong suspicion is that you haven't actually run the assignment line. It's behaving as though it's pointing at random memory. Are you certain that the assignment has run? Is __cellDataShadowArray2D defined as a strong variable?

Comment: Nice idea @RobNapier !  I sometimes fall into this trap myself.  Put the breakpoint on the line AFTER the assignment, not the assignment itself :).

Comment: Given the discussion @jessex mentioned below, it would be a good thing to try GDB and see if it has any problem with this code.

Answer (score 1):

- make sure the line of code is actually evaluated before doing the test.

It is clear that __cellDataShadowArray2D is pointing to an empty instance of a compiled constant string; @"".  That means it cannot be an over-release or anything like that;  it means that the assignment has not yet happened (or you are attempting to debug optimized code and the debugger is confused due to optimizations).

- po of non-object types doesn't make sense
- `retainCount` is useless.  Don't call it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/142235?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a LLDB problem. I had the same, coud not debug at all. I switched back to GDB and it was ok